# How do you cross-breed flowers?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

When I got the recipe for the watering can, the game mentioned something about hybrid flowers, but didn't explain anything about what that meant or how to do it. How can I cross-breed my flowers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The game does not go into exact detail how to breed new flowers, but [this guide](https://www.newsweek.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-flower-guide-list-how-breed-hybrid-1493937) has detailed how to do it.

Basically, in a grid of 3x3, arrange your flowers in an 'X-shape'. Keeping a space empty between flowers is important - this is where the newly bred flower will appear.

```
F - F
- F -
F - F
```

Where 'F' is a flower, and '-' is an empty space.

Generally, possible combinations are made up out of basic color mixing. If the upper two flowers are Red and White, the most likely flower to be bred in the empty space between them will be pink.

It seems that the possible combinations are 'endless'. At the bottom of the guide I linked above, there's a list of more exotic or adventurous combinations.

It should also be noted that not all flower types can be bred:

- Carnations: Breed white.
- Cosmos: Breed pink, orange and black.
- Dandelions: Can't breed.
- Jacob's Ladder: Can't breed.
- Lilies: Breed pink, orange and black.
- Pansies: Breed orange, blue, red (special), purple, orange (special)
- Roses: Breed pink, purple, orange, black, red (special), blue and gold
- Tulips: Breed pink, orange, black, purple.
- Violets: Breed pink.

Possible color combinations:

- Pink: White + Red
- Yellow: Red + Orange
- White: Yellow + Purple
- Black: Red + Red

And the more 'adventurous' combinations:

- Black Cosmos: Orange + Orange
- Blue Pansies: White + White
- Special Red Pansies: Blue + Red
- Purple Pansies: Red Special + Red Special / Orange Special + Orange Special
- Special Orange Pansies: Blue + Orange
- Pink Roses: Red + Red
- Purple Roses: White + White
- Special Red Roses: Orange + Purple
- Blue Roses: Red Special + Red Special
- Gold Roses: Dried Black Rose + Gold Watering Can

Below is a screenshot of how to plant the flowers:

[image: How to plant the flowers]

Source(s): [newsweek.com](https://www.newsweek.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-flower-guide-list-how-breed-hybrid-1493937)